# How to convert XLSB files to XLSX or CSV with a script in macOS? I've tried R and JavaScript without success?

Tags: javascript, r, excel, bash, xlsb

I've tried `R` and a `JavaScript` library [j](https://github.com/SheetJS/j) without success. I saw a way to do it with libreoffice CLI, so should I try with `bash`?

With j I did:

`j file.xlsb --xlsx --output file.xlsx`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is bash related, but sure you could try [running LibreOffice from the command line](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters) to convert `xlsb` to `csv`:

```
soffice --convert-to csv file.xlsb
```

Or if you have many files to convert:

```
soffice --convert-to csv *.xlsb
```