# importing xlsb into R

Tags: r, xlsb

I downloaded a bunch of `xlsb` files from a public database. Each file is about 60MB.

How can I import these files into `R` without having access to Microsoft Excel?

I tried opening them with LibreOffice and converting them from the command line via
`soffice --convert-to`. But this results in a much smaller file with a huge loss of data. I had this problem with both Linux Mint and with a Microsoft Windows machine.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Nadia! Upon suggested edits by others I tried to make your question more readable. I hope you like the edit, if not feel free to undo. Unfortunately I don`t know how to solve your problem, but you could probably make it easier for others to help you if you provide a link to one of these files and give more details on the error messages / problems you get when opening them with LibreOffice.

Comment: Have a look at the `excel.link` package, as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54989216/5785085)

Comment: I already tried with excel.link package, but when I try to install it I just got a message saying it's a Windows only package. I don't get any error message when trying to open the files or convert them to csv, simply, the conversion produces a file which is not including all data, but only a part of them. You can find all xlsb files here http://www.wiod.org/database/wiots_pyp16